Combine token approval and contract invocation in a single call
When using ethers.js we end up doing two calls to transfer tokens to a smart contract:
await token.approve(contractAddress, amount);
await contract.myFunction(); // This function uses the tokens

This is not a good user experience as they have to approve two different steps with their wallet.
Is there any way to combine both the token approval and the contract execution in a single popup?

I see you added a bounty. Thanks for that, will be interesting to see if people know of better alternatives! I'm sure there are various standards, but I fear the problem is adoption - third parties don't want to implement yet another token standard.

Yes, but nothing widely adopted.
Some options:

Another token standard. For example ERC-777 supports callbacks, where adding approval could callback the contract that needs the approval. This standard is not widely supported.
Account Abstraction. This allows multicalls (many actions in one transaction), but there are not very many implementations for this yet. Furthermore, there are also not many wallets supporting this currently.
Many apps require an infinite approval from users. So users approve an infinite amount of tokens to be spent and after that they never need to perform approvals anymore. Not very secure, since all tokens can be stolen if the app gets compromised.


You can look at Permit2, which solves two problems in the traditional ERC20 approach:

The user never has to submit a separate approve() transaction.
There is no longer a necessary evil of dangling allowances since permit messages grant an instantaneous allowance that is often spent right away. These messages can also choose a more reasonable allowance amount and, more importantly, an expiration time on when the permit message can be consumed.


But this can't be included in a "single popup" as the original question stated, if I understand correctly? The user first has to allow the signature and then use that.

Note that Permit2 creates more problems that it solves - some history here https://x.com/moo9000/status/1593400084313546764 - a proper solution is to use a token standard that is user friendly and that token standard is not ERC-20.

Yes, it is possible, though not in the way you might ideally envision it, especially when interacting with the injected provider (e.g., MetaMask). It's important to keep in mind the user's experience in terms of signing approvals while balancing security and efficiency.
The Permit mechanism (EIP-2612) aims to optimize gas costs associated with token transfers by combining the approval and transfer into a single action. However, it's important to note that this does not completely eliminate the requirement for signing multiple transactions.
To combine multiple signatures into a single transaction, you’d typically need a third-party solution, such as a relayer or a bundler, which allows you to batch multiple transactions and present them to the user as a single action. This would give the user the impression of one action.
Alternatively, as mentioned, using other standards like ERC-777 or other smart contracts will allow for more flexible token operations.
Ultimately, the choice depends on design philosophy and trade-offs between simplicity, security, and gas efficiency.
In short, both Permit and bundling mechanisms are effective approaches, but they require different trade-offs in terms of user experience and design complexity.
